# Check if connection is established on port

Tags: python, sockets

I have the to check if the port is open, but I'm not sure how to extend this also check if the connection is established.

```
import socket

ip_address_machine='127.0.0.1'
port_to_try=3389

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = s.connect_ex((ip_address_machine, port_to_try))
    s.close()
    if(result == 0) :
        print ("Port ",port_to_try, "is open on machine ", ip_address_machine)
    else:
        print ("Port ",port_to_try, "is not open on machine ", ip_address_machine)
except:
    print("Machine is off")
```

Comment: `s.connect_ex()` establishes a connection, or provides an error code. It does not merely determine if a port is available on the other side.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket-objects

Comment: ok, so is there a way to determine if there are connections over this port using the socket?

Comment: It is difficult to know exactly what you are asking.  It turns out that knowing if a socket is still good, i.e. still connected, is a tricky thing, as tcp/ip is supposed to be resilient to intermittent network failure.  If you are asking if we can determine who is connected, when a port supports multiple users, all of the connections are independent and can not spy on each other.  The server, of course, can read all of the incoming messages and copy them to other sockets, as in a chat server.  The `lsof` command in Linux can tell you who or what is connected to a socket.

Comment: Good comment. Basically I'm trying to test if there is already a remote desktop connection running on the server. Not convinced this can be done from a different machine though

Comment: You might look into listing all the open ports and processes using them on the server.  Simple not being able to connect doesn't tell you much, but the local system knows a fair bit about open sockets.  On Linux, start with netstat.